# Ubuntu 17.10 to access Windows Files Shares within workplace IT

Tags: windows, 17.10, samba

On Ubuntu 17.10 I am unable to log in to the workplace file services from the file browser. After having investigated this seems to be a deeper Samba related issue.

```
$ smbclient -W WINWORKGRP  -U 'my.name@my-domain.com' -L //dc1/
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter my.name@my-domain.com's password: 
SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
```

I need help debugging this...

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the following lines to `/etc/samba/smb.conf` solved the issue:

```
client use spnego = no
client ntlmv2 auth = no
workgroup = WINWIRKGRP
```